# how to use if statement in Group_Concat in Mysql

Tags: mysql

After my head bangs to the wall, I am trying to have a pivot data with this sample table content.

```
id--------------lastname-----total----rd               
0511-02-0318    Salvador    8.99    2015-09-08
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  0       2015-09-08
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  7.95    2015-09-07
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  8.69    2015-09-04
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  6.81    2015-09-01
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  8.86    2015-08-29
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  6.16    2015-08-28
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  8.66    2015-08-27
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  8.03    2015-08-26
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  8.68    2015-08-25
0214-02-0616    Alfaro  8.75    2015-08-24
0511-02-0318    Salvador 9.17   2015-09-09
0511-02-0318    Salvador 9.28   2015-09-10
0415-02-0960    Martin   0      2015-09-18
0415-02-0960    Martin  10.39   2015-09-17
0415-02-0960    Martin  8.44    2015-09-16
0415-02-0960    Martin  10.9    2015-09-15
0415-02-0960    Martin  10.91   2015-09-14
0415-02-0960    Martin  9.91    2015-09-11
0415-02-0960    Martin  10.31   2015-09-10
0415-02-0960    Martin  11.16   2015-09-09
0415-02-0960    Martin  12.04   2015-09-08
0415-02-0960    Martin  9.42    2015-09-07
0415-02-0960    Martin  10.43   2015-09-04
0415-02-0960    Martin  10.39   2015-09-03
```

This is my working attemp Query but i think i missed up something:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
set @sdate = '2015-09-01';
set @edate = '2015-09-06';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(

distinct concat('total=',list_of_dates)

/*distinct concat('if(p.rd=''',list_of_dates,''',p.total',0,')')*/

) INTO @sql from
(SELECT ADDDATE(date(@sdate), INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS list_of_dates
FROM (
SELECT a.a
FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
) a
JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
WHERE 
@i < DATEDIFF(date(@edate),date(@sdate))) as a;





set @sql = concat('select id,   lastname,   total,   rd,',@sql,'  from
(select ''0511-02-0318'' as id, ''Salvador'' as lastname,   8.99 as total,  ''2015-09-08'' as rd union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 0   ,''2015-09-08''  union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 7.95,   ''2015-09-07''  union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 8.69,   ''2015-09-04''  union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 6.81,   ''2015-09-01''  union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 8.86,   ''2015-08-29''  union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 6.16,   ''2015-08-28''  union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 8.66,   ''2015-08-27''  union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 8.03,   ''2015-08-26''  union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 8.68,   ''2015-08-25''  union all
select  ''0214-02-0616'',   ''Alfaro'', 8.75,   ''2015-08-24''  union all
select  ''0511-02-0318'',   ''Salvador'',   9.28,   ''2015-09-10''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 0,  ''2015-09-18''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 10.39,  ''2015-09-17''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 8.44,   ''2015-09-16''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 10.9,   ''2015-09-15''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 10.91,  ''2015-09-14''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 9.91,   ''2015-09-11''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 10.31,  ''2015-09-10''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 11.16,  ''2015-09-09''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 12.04,  ''2015-09-08''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 9.42,   ''2015-09-07''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 10.43,  ''2015-09-04''  union all
select  ''0415-02-0960'',   ''Martin'', 10.39,  ''2015-09-03'')data');



PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here's is my attempt output:

[image]

I want an output if `pivot date` is Equal to `rd` then the pivot `date content` is become the `value` of the `total` but if not equal then the value become 0. Also the `id and lastname become distinct` Also with the pivot date the `total=` should be remove.

I've tried on that sample commented code but no luck.

This one work but it return only one row.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("SUM(IF(data.rd='",DATE(list_of_dates),"',`total`,0)) AS `",list_of_dates,"`")) as `dates`
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the data in a table? In your code you seem to be generating the data rather than reading from a table. What's the name of the table?

Comment: I am preparing the data to be ready to update but it's came from  my table it's the same.. you can run the query anytime. without any table needed.

Comment: @redzol: Did that work for you? If so, please mark as accepted and up-vote. If not, let me know what error you got, or what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** *I changed part of the code to order the date sub total columns*

I started out by creating a `select` statement that  produces the final results, then wrote code to generate that `select` statement. I also created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11178/20/7) to produce the statement and results.

Rather than fake the data in the procedure, I created a real table. You will have to modify the code to fit your particular needs since I didn't have the name of the table you would be using.

This works in several steps:

- Set the parameters (start/end dates)
- Get a list of dates from the data for the range specified.
- Generate the SQL statement.
- Execute the SQL statement.

Here's the test SQL statement I wrote as a model:

```
SELECT 
    `id`,
    `lastname`,
    SUM(`total`) AS `total`,
    SUM(if(`rd` = '2015-09-01',`total`,0)) AS `total:2015-09-01`,
    SUM(if(`rd` = '2015-09-02',`total`,0)) AS `total:2015-09-02`,
    SUM(if(`rd` = '2015-09-03',`total`,0)) AS `total:2015-09-03`,
    SUM(if(`rd` = '2015-09-04',`total`,0)) AS `total:2015-09-04`,
    SUM(if(`rd` = '2015-09-05',`total`,0)) AS `total:2015-09-05`,
    SUM(if(`rd` = '2015-09-06',`total`,0)) AS `total:2015-09-06`
FROM `test_table`
WHERE `rd` BETWEEN @sdate AND @edate
GROUP BY `id`,`lastname`
ORDER BY `id`,`lastname`
```

And here's the code to generate and run that SQL statement:

```
/* Set the parameters */
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @dates = NULL;
SET @sdate = '2015-09-01';
SET @edate = '2015-09-06';

/* Get a list of dates, and format as the column def for the SQL SELECT */
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SUM(IF(`rd` = '",DATE(`rd`),"',`total`,0)) AS `total:",DATE(`rd`),"`")) as `dates`
FROM (SELECT `rd` FROM `test_table` GROUP BY `rd` ORDER BY `rd`) AS a
WHERE a.`rd` BETWEEN @sdate AND @edate
INTO @dates;

/* Generate the SQL SELECT */
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT `id`,`lastname`,SUM(`total`) AS `total`,",@dates," FROM `test_table` WHERE `rd` BETWEEN @sdate AND @edate GROUP BY `id`,`lastname` ORDER BY `id`,`lastname`")
INTO @sql;

/* Execute the SELECT */
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the post i'll try this.

Comment: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'rd' in 'field list'

Comment: Where? Which SQL statement?

Comment: Which SQL statement gave the error, and show the entire error message. Did you try the SQL Fiddle?

Comment: As i update the question above there's no error now but it gives me only one row..

Comment: Did you try the SQL Fiddle?

Comment: In your update, you added just part of the SQL statement. No way to tell why you are only getting one row without the rest of the statement.

Comment: Didn't try sql fiddle.. I am modifying the script now.Hoping to get the result.. Thanks to your time man. Greatly appreciated.